# Scroll view problem?

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

I arranged imageview in the scrollview if the image is larger than the display, it shows blur edges (not sharp edges).

```
 <ScrollView 
    android:layout_marginTop="35dip"
    android:id="@+id/sv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

   <HorizontalScrollView 
       android:id="@+id/hsv"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">   

       <FrameLayout 
          android:id="@+id/framelayout"
          android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent">

          <ImageView 
               android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

see the image at edges right and down : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38493970/device-2011-09-07-144456.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look out the `android:fadingEdge` set it to `none`.